# Jenkins not detected when scanning with Nessus

Tags: nessus

Running Credentialed Basic Network Scans I tried looking at the scan results for details regarding the latest set of vulns for Jenkins. While I am not sure if my version of Jenkins is affected, the service is not detected at all.

It seems that the scan should include the Jenkins Detection plugin (https://www.tenable.com/plugins/nessus/65054) though it refuses to trigger for the scanned host.

Am I incorrect, is the plugin not included in the Basic Network Scan?

If the plugin is included and my scan should detect Jenkins, are there any other caveats?

I am running a limited number of ports for the port scan, could this affect the plugin? Feels strange as the credentialed scan, once service account has logged on, should not rely on the port scan. Or would this fall under port scan based service detection?

Any feedback/Suggestions appreciated!